# Is there a way to include null values in a list in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, console-application

I have a text file filled with several lines of data, and I would like to split it into 5 different elements like so..

[image: Data]

I am successfully reading in the data and putting it into an array. Now I would like to split each part of the text up into different lists so I can compare the data against one another.

I have currently managed to read in the first 4 elements of each line into their relevant lists but the 5th one is throwing me the error "System.IndexOutOfRangeException" which I can only assume is because the first line it reads in has no value for the 5th element?

So my question is, is there a way to populate null values when writing them to a number of lists?

I've tried manually assigning the size of the array and lists but I still get the same error.

Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Reading in file containing data from BT Code Evaluation sheet (for testing purposes).
        // Each line gets stored into a string array, each element is one line of the data.txt file.
        //String[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Ad\Desktop\data.txt");

        String[] lines = new String[5] {"monitorTime", "localTime", "actor", "action", "actor2"};

        lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Ad\Desktop\data.txt");

        char delimiter = ' ';
        List<String> monitorTime = new List<String>();
        List<String> localTime = new List<String>();
        List<String> actor = new List<String>();
        List<String> action = new List<String>();
        List<String> actor2 = new List<String>();

        // Foreach loop displays the lines of text in the data file.
        foreach (String line in lines)
        {
            // Writes the data to the console.
            Console.WriteLine(line);

            String[] data = new String[5] { "monitorTime", "localTime", "actor", "action", "actor2" };
            data = line.Split(delimiter);

            monitorTime.Add(data[0]);
            localTime.Add(data[1]);
            actor.Add(data[2]);
            action.Add(data[3]);
            actor2.Add(data[4]);
        }

        foreach (String time in monitorTime)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(time);
        }

        foreach (String time in localTime)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(time);
        }

        foreach (String name in actor)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }

        foreach (String actions in action)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(actions);
        }

        foreach (String name in actor2)
        {
            if (name != null)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("UNKNOWN");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(actor2);
            }
        }

        // Creates an empty line between the data and the following text.
        Console.WriteLine("");
        // Displays message in console.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to analyse data and create report...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: You really should copy and paste code into your question instead of posting images.

Comment: @B34R You can still edit this question (you should)

Comment: Check the array boundaries and if it doesn't have enough items, add `null` instead: `actor2.Add(data.length > 4 ? data[4] : null)`

Comment: You should also post the data as text. We can't copy/paste an image.

Comment: I have edited my post to show the code in text form. After updating my code provided by Matt Burland it no longer throws me an error, instead it outputs this:
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Comment: Console.WriteLine(actor2); should be Console.WriteLine(name);

Comment: Ah that was it! Thank you all for your help!

Comment: that for sure did not cause index range exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the bounds of you array before you try to add. If their aren't enough items you can add null instead.

For example:

```
actor2.Add(data.length > 4 ? data[4] : null)
```

(Note: You could do the same type of check on the other items as well, unless you are positive that the last item is the only one that might be null)

This is using the [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator), but you could also use a simple `if/else`, but it'll be more verbose. It's equivalent to:

```
if (data.length > 4) 
{
    actor2.Add(data[4]);
}
else
{
    actor2.Add(null);
}
```

This along with `Console.WriteLine(name);` instead of `Console.WriteLine(actor2);` should fix you immediate problem.

However, a much better design here would be to have a single list of objects with `MonitorTime`, `LocalTime`, `Actor`, `Action` and `Actor2` properties. That way you don't ever have to worry that the 5 parallel arrays might get out of sync.

For example, create a class like this:

```
public class DataItem
{
    public string MonitorTime { get; set; }
    public string LocalTime { get; set; }
    public string Actor { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Actor2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then instead of your 5 `List<String>`, you have one `List<DataItem>`:

```
List<DataItem> dataList = new List<DataItem>();
```

Then in your loop to populate it you'd do something like:

```
data = line.Split(delimiter);
dataList.Add(new DataItem() 
{
    MonitorTime = data[0],
    LocalTime = data[1],
    Actor = data[2],
    Action = data[3],
    Actor2 = data.length > 4 ? data[4] : null
});
```

Then you can access them later with something like:

```
foreach (var item in dataList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.MonitorTime);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Whenever I try to add all properties to a single list `List<string> monitorTime, localTime, actor, action, actor2 = new List<string>();` I receive the error of an unassigned value in my foreach loop, am I assigning them wrong?

Comment: @B34R: I added an example of the better way to handle this.

Comment: That works great! Now I have one more issue.. I'm trying to output to console a series of text but the order in which it is outputted depends on the LocalTime, would I need to convert the LocalTime string to an int/long then use the `<` operands to compare the 2? Or could I do it whilst they are strings?

Comment: @B34R: use `int.Parse` (or maybe `int.TryParse`) to convert `LocalTime` to an `int` (you should probably make the property `LocalTime` and int instead of a string and do the conversion when you populate it) and then you can use `Sort` or maybe better use the LINQ extension method `OrderBy`

Comment: Great I've managed to get everything working. When I output to the console I only want the most recent node sent so in order from the 1st timestamp, is there a way for me to output only the latest timestamps data for each individual "actor" (luke, vader, r2d2 etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

In your `for each` you should be checking to see if the index exists before populating the object.

```
foreach (String line in lines)
{
    // Writes the data to the console.
    Console.WriteLine(line);

    String[] data = new String[5] { "monitorTime", "localTime", "actor", "action", "actor2" };
    data = line.Split(delimiter);

    monitorTime.Add(data[0]);
    localTime.Add(data[1]);
    actor.Add(data[2]);
    action.Add(data[3]);
    if (data.Length > 4) {
        actor2.Add(data[4]);
    }
}
```

There's better ways to do this but this is a simple solution for now.

Comment: Since this doesn't actually add a `null` when `data.Length <= 4`, this potentially causes the indexes in the 5 collections to no longer line up. In the end, `actor2` would only have 4 items, while the others have 7.